# Fill Arrays with random values

Tags: javascript, arrays, processing

I have **two 1D arrays** and I want to fill them with 10 unique random x,y values in Processing.

For example:

```
x  y 
-  -
3, 9
2, 4
6, 2
7, 5
```

My arrays are:

**Table1** for the X values and

**Table2** for the Y values.

My issue is if the number 3,9 exists already I don't want 9,3 to be stored in the arrays.

I can identify when x,y value (or y,x) already exists but once I replace it I cannot check if the **new** generated random number exist in the previous indexes.

This is what I have tried so far. However if 3 values aldready exists, the arrays Table1 and Table2 will store only 7 values instead of 10.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {       
   x=(int)random(6);
   y=(int)random(6);
 if  ((Table1[i] != x && Table2[i] != y) || (Table1[i] != y && Table2[i] != x))
   {
    Table1[i] = x; 
    Table2[i] = y;
   }
```

Any ideas how to control that?

Comment: Is there a range of values you'd like to restrict the random numbers to?

Comment: @Martin Yes from 0 to 6.

Comment: How can you restrict from 0 to 6 if you want 10 unique random numbers?

Comment: There isn't going to be a magical solution to this. You're going to have to check what's already in the array against what you're trying to insert. Do you have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Martin because the OP wants combinations, not individual numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I can think about only two ways of achieving it, and none is ideal.

- Check if the numbers you generated already exists, and if it's the case, generate anothers until you get a unique combination. It could be expensive with a small range of possibilities, because it's random, and if you're very unlucky you could even end in an infinite loop...
- Create an array containing every possible combination. Then, instead of generating random numbers, you'll generate a random index into this array (an integer in [0;array.length[). After that, you'll have to remove the choosen combination from the array (that way it won't be available for the next loop), and the inverse of it (if you picked (9;3), you have to remove (9;3) AND (3;9)).

Answer (score 1):

I have this code that might help you,

first declare your arrays :

```
var a = [];
var b = [];
```

then you can call a function that does everything for you

```
fill(a,b)
```

The definition of this function should be something like this :

```
function fill(a, b) { 
       var arr = [];
       while(arr.length<10) {
             var pair = randomPair();
             if (arr.indexOf(pair.join(','))==-1 || arr.indexOf(pair.reverse().join(','))==-1) {
                a.push(pair[0]);
                b.push(pair[1]);
                arr.push(pair.join(','));
             }
       }
    }
```

then the defintion of other used function is :

```
function randomPair () { 
   return [ parseInt(Math.random()*7) , parseInt(Math.random()*7) ]
}
```

so, obviously, the randomPair function returns 2 values x and y. the `fill` function tests if the pair already exists or not in normal order or reversed order. if not it's added both a, and b which are references to your main arrays;

Answer (score -1):

I see no other option as to walk to the whole arrays again to check if they contains your new generated value(s).

Comment: What is the difference between "answer" and "comment"? I can't even vote for answers since I have no reputation...